# C# using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, winrm

My goal is to run a task on a remote server for this I would like to use WinRM. Having trouble making this work.

Running from powershell window it works fine doing like this.

```bsh
New-PSSession -ComputerName y49800 | Enter-PSSession
E:
E:\work\application.exe
```

Doing this from C# is another story. Tried many options but nothings really works.
As a step I tried to run the first command like mentioned below. Looks like it runs fine, but if I change the domputer name to something that does not exsist it does give me an output error.
I also need to run the next steps where I change drive and execute my program.

```cs
try {
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create()) {
        // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
        // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
        var instance = PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"New-PSSession -ComputerName y49800 | Enter-PSSession");

        //// use "AddParameter" to add a single parameter to the last command/script on the pipeline.
        //PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", "parameter 1 value!");

        // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
        Collection <PSObject> PSOutput = instance.Invoke();
        // loop through each output object item
        foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput) {
            // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
            // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential NRE.
            if (outputItem != null) {
                //TODO: do something with the output item 
                test = outputItem.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception exc) {
    System.Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use :) Look into `Import-Session`/`Invoke-Command` or `WSManConnectionInfo` if you want control over the remote runspace